# Por que o nome do modo de articulação anterior é no caso da língua da direção do palato duro e não do palato mole se é o mole está a atrás?

Tags: fonética

Já que para as vogais são definidos os nomes dos modos de articulação dessa maneira: anterior e posterior, baseados na posição da língua, por que na definição parece contrário ao nome dado? Apesar de não existir uma direção absoluta, não deveria ser o contrário já que o palato duro é na frente do palato mole pensando intuitivamente ao levar em conta que os dentes são a frente da boca?

Anteriores - são articuladas com a língua elevada em direção ao palato duro, próximo ao dentes. Ex.: é (pé), ê (dedo), i (botina).

Posteriores - são articuladas quando a língua se dirige ao palato mole. Ex.: ó (pó), ô (lobo), u (resumo).

Comment: Não entendo... anterior está em frente, posterior está por trás, tudo parece-me certo. Por que anterior estaria por trás? Por que posterior estaria em frente?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo que entendo a dúvida é apenas sobre o uso de "anterior" para se referir à parte da frente da boca e "posterior" para a de trás.

Mas esses são simplesmente como esses termos são definidos em anatomia:

> [**anterior**](https://dicionario.priberam.org/anterior) | *adj. 2 g.*
> 2. Que está adiante ou na parte da frente (ex.: *dor na parte anterior da perna; membros anteriores*). = DIANTEIRO ≠ POSTERIOR, TRASEIRO
> [**posterior**](https://dicionario.priberam.org/POSTERIOR) | *adj. 2 g. | n. m.*
> 3. Que está situado na parte de trás ou na parte que se opõe à frente (ex.: *patas posteriores; parte posterior da perna*). = TRASEIRO ≠ ANTERIOR, DIANTEIRO, FRONTAL

E o palato duro fica próximo aos dentes, ou seja, na parte da frente da boca — na parte dianteira, na parte *anterior* da boca; enquanto o palato mole fica na parte de trás da boca — na parte traseira, *posterior* da boca.

Em uma imagem da [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anatomical_terms_of_location) (em inglês, mas os termos relevantes se escrevem da mesma forma):

[image]

Comment: As an MD, I can only say "great answer, great illustration".  +1